# how to install a pybind11 module to a specific directory

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I am trying to have my pybind11 module(MyModule) installed into my BUILD_DIR directory. I tried "install", "set_target_properties" and "set_property" - but none works[make install does work for "install" but I really wanted set_target_properties or set_property like the rest of my entire project does(without make install) which is one step and does not leave behind the "so" in the current dir as well] and it didnt even throw errors. It always installs the "so" file in the current directory rather than BUILD_DIR.

```
pybind11_add_module(MyModule MyFile.cpp)
install( TARGETS MyModule DESTINATION "${BUILD_DIR}" )
set_target_properties( MyModule PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${BUILD_DIR}" )
set_property( TARGET MyModule PROPERTY RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${BUILD_DIR}" )
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi! I assume you're using cmake. What commands do you run other than cmake? `make install`?

Comment: Thanks @unddoch Yep cmake and then make. "make install" does work for "install" but I really wanted set_target_properties or set_property like the rest of my entire project does(without make install). Sorry I should have made it clearer in the question - Just edited the qn

Comment: In that case, you might want to `add_custom_target(COMMAND ...)`.

Comment: @unddoch Yep add_custom_target is what I was doing as a work around(doing a copy and then rm), but was wondering whats wrong with a simple set_property that works with all other than pybind11 module.

Comment: By default, `pybind11_add_module` creates a `MODULE` type of the library: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#pybind11-add-module. Such library type is treated by CMake as "**Library**" output artifact: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#library-output-artifacts. E.g its output directory is controlled by property [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), not by `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Perfect - Thank you. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept.